# What Commander Am I?

Tags: riddle, word

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

---

**What Commander Am I?**
<sub>The answer must explain (and fit with) all of the lines</sub>

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are...

> AN ITCH!

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> Itches come randomly and from nowhere.

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

> You get no verbal commands but the command is always the same, SCRATCH ME!

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> You gotta scratch that itch!

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

> Some people are more itchy than others, but everyone itches

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> Usually when you itch it goes away, but sometimes it just [makes you itchy elsewhere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referred_itch)

Comment: yes, thank God for your answer! I was ready to go crazy over here. Yours fits the last line **very well**, unlike any of the others!

Comment: Thank you for the fun riddle!

I also kind of hate you a little because now I am *SO ITCHY*.  Sadness.

Comment: How is an itch a "commander"?  It's not.  This riddle fails due to major abuse (in a non riddly way) of fundamental definitions.  ... An itch is an impulse, sensation, or even a reflex.  That is in no way any kind of commander.  Ask 10,000 people on the street to describe an itch.  The word "commander" will not be used once.

Comment: I was hoping it would be dance commander :(

Comment: @Brock Adams Yes because we only use dictionary definitions in riddles.

Comment: @BrockAdams Why is an itch a commander? Because it **commands** you to scratch! It's a riddle. It is not supposed to be so direct that it's a giveaway. If you don't like it, down-vote. I've pretty much lost hope that this site can become a good puzzle site anyway. We regularly have decent (even good) puzzles getting <5 votes, which is <25 points, and answers that only partially fit/ forced/ just not good, getting over 50 points. The **ONLY** incentive that one has to make a puzzle at all is for the sheer joy of it, because the effort surely won't be worth the measly points he receives for it.

Comment: @BrockAdams Also, it's too easy for people to create multiple accounts, and up-vote their own puzzles and answers, skewing the vote accuracy (For example, I suspect that CodeNewbie is Rand al'thor). I think I've just lost interest, not just because of this puzzle, but gradually over the past few weeks, it's just starting to feel useless to put time into the site.

Answer (score 8):

Inspired by Alex's answer, I think the commander refers to a

> Yawn.

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> You never know when you will yawn.

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

> The yawn forces your mouth wide without making the slightest sound. The demands of a yawn are always the same-"Go to sleep NOW!"

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> If you keep ignoring your yawns, they become more intense and frequent. And as you yawn more and more, the desire to sleep increases further.

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

> Those who haven't got enough sleep at night will yawn more than others. As night rolls around, almost everyone gets a yawn or two before they take to their bed.

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> Once you catch some sleep, you will stop yawning. But if someone sees you yawning, they will also inadvertently start yawning.

Comment: Anybody else yawn like 3-4 times while reading this answer?

Comment: Well, technically, it's compelling you to take in more oxygen, so it can give a short awakening boost to the brain. But indirectly, it's compelling you to sleep?

Comment: The last 2 lines...so, if you're saying that the obeying is going to sleep, then it doesn't really make sense, because it is saying that the yawning will USUALLY leave for a while when you go to sleep, but in fact your yawning will always leave if you go to sleep. You don't have to try so hard to make the intended answer fit.

Comment: The wide opening of the mouth is the action that you are compelled into. @JLee, I'm not sure now if you're trying to make me fit the clue to the correct answer, or trying to let me know that the answer is wrong.

Comment: @JLee If we're close, say "you're close". If we're wrong, say "that's wrong". You're playing semantics in a riddle, and whether you want it to or not, "Yawn" fits quite well as a solution, so give it to him straight.

Comment: @Roland I didn't and don't intend to confuse. I thought that "You don't have to try so hard to make the intended answer fit." was a pretty clear way of saying it ain't right.

Comment: Weird. The contagion expressed in the comments of Amagii's answer made me think of this. And here it is ;)

Answer (score 4):

Haha I doubt this is the answer, but it fits rather amusingly.

You are

> Smartphone system update notifications!

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> Nobody knows when the update notification will appear!

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

> No words necessary, just that darn symbol at the top of your notification bar that sits there FOREVER. The demand, obviously, is that you perform your system update.

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> Seriously, it's super annoying. At least on my phone, I can't swipe it away or clear it from my notifications unless I perform the actual update.

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

> Some phones probably require system updates more than others, but anybody with a smartphone will need to do it at some point. Although maybe iPhones do it automatically, I wouldn't know.

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> After you actually perform the update, the notification disappears. Alas, I am unable to make the last line fit, specifically the "nearby" part.

Comment: hahaha I can't say that I feel your pain, since I have a flip phone. :/

Comment: This is the only answer that can even remotely be shoehorned to fit the term "commander".

Answer (score 3):

> Hunger, thirst, addiction, and the voices in your head all seem to fit but I'm going to go with Hunger.

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
 I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> Every time somebody shows up with good food, you're suddenly hungry. Any attempt to fit with a food schedule is going to be hard, even if you're at an office job.

Without a word, I compel you into action.
 My demands upon you are always the same.

> Feed! Well, your rumbling stomach sure doesn't pronounce it well, even if that is the command.

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
 You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> An empty stomach is very annoying, and hard to resist.

I do visit some people more than others,
 But all will deal with me at some point.

> Some people need to eat more, and nobody can go without food completely (yet.)

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
 But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> You might not be hungry after you eat, but if anyone sees what you're eating, well, they might get very hungry.

Comment: I already mentioned hunger in the first answer's comment

Comment: also, how does hunger reappear nearby for more? That part doesn't fit too well.

Comment: the hunger would appear in someone ELSE nearby.

Comment: Also if you're on a diet but everyone around you is eating ice cream, that's really annoying.

Comment: i see what you mean, but it seems to not fit that well to me

Comment: Well I suppose it depends on how you handle hunger. It's certainly not the same thing if everyone's eating stuff you don't like. But if it's something like... *donuts*, then that would make the entire office jealous, annoyed, and hungry if you didn't share.

Comment: yes, those donut phrases do have a way of annoying! :)

Answer (score 2):

Continuing on this "involuntary physical reflex" trend:

> I think it's a sneeze.

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> A sneeze is not predictable; even if you're trying to provoke it with pepper or dust, it cannot be *accurately* determined when the sneeze will occur.

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

> Not much to do but to let go and sneeze.

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> You can try to hold it back; pinch your nose as such, but the need reappears shortly after.

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

> Due to allergies, colds, etc, some people sneeze a lot more than others; and everyone sneezes at some point.

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> Usually a good sneeze gets rid of the need, but double sneezes are not uncommon either.

Comment: thou I think you're on the same train as I do, You might want to explain how your answer fits into each line of the riddle?

Answer (score 1):

First attempt!:

You are:

> [The Sleepy Commander](http://rayn44.deviantart.com/art/Sleepy-commander-478524496)

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> You might usually sleep at night but you will get sleepy all of a sudden

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

> Once you're sleepy you will want to go the sleep

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> The more you struggle the more you want to sleep.

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

> some people need more sleep than others

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
but sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> Once you obey (get some sleep), you will be fine until you're sleepy again.

Comment: It fits fairly well, but the annoy part, and the last 2 lines don't fit that well, in my opinion. When I am sleepy but don't sleep, I'm tired, but not really annoyed. Also, when i am hungry and don't eat, I crave food, but am not really annoyed. Sleep doesn't really appear nearby for more, does it?

Comment: I think it fits perfectly except for the first few lines. Most people have good sleep routines.

Comment: Ah, I am sorry I misleaded many thinking into all sort of body reactions haha

Comment: Eh, it's not too bad. First thought that came to me after reading the riddle was poo.    so....

Comment: @Spacemonkey Giggled after reading your comment and first line of the riddle

Comment: It honestly only doesn't fit the last stanza/clue too. Just sayin'   ;)

Comment: @spacemonkey I will use "near miss (the toliet)"  as an explanation

Answer (score 0):

You could be

> my diaphragm (of the respiratory system)

You cannot accurately predict my arrival.
I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere.

> Most people can't predict an onset of the hiccups, yawns, and sneezes.

Without a word, I compel you into action.
My demands upon you are always the same.

> The spasms begin suddenly without warning. All hiccups, yawns, and sneezes are quite similar.

Choose to ignore me, and I'll annoy you.
You have a strong desire to obey my will.

> Hiccups are involuntary (and yawns somewhat), and ignoring them will do no good. It can be hard to resist yawns and sneezes, as the urge sometimes lingers well after resisting.

I do visit some people more than others,
But all will deal with me at some point.

> Some people get hiccups more often than others, but everybody gets them at some point. People who are tired more will yawn more. People with allergies, for example, sneeze more than others.

Once obeyed, I usually leave for awhile,
But sometimes I reappear nearby for more.

> For yawns, "once obeyed" must mean sleeping. For sneezing, "once obeyed" must refer to succumbing to the urge. For hiccups, they leave as mysteriously as they appeared, but both can return again suddenly.

Comment: Similarly to CodeNewbie's answer of "Yawn," a hiccup **IS** the spasm that you refer to. What does that spasm compel you to do?

Comment: @JLee I've changed my answer to diaphram, the commander of involuntary respiratory spasms.

Comment: This is confusing to me. If your answer is diaphragm, then the diaphragm must be the one saying, "You cannot accurately predict my arrival. I seem to appear randomly out of nowhere."

Answer (score 0):

> The need to pee.

I think all but the last line are pretty self-explanatory.

> Think about when you see someone else go pee, or even just hear that they have to, and suddenly you have to pee too.